# Kentico Permission Training, Best Practices

Tags: kentico

Hi guys:: I am looking for any videos/training material besides the documentation that can walk a person through the permission and workflow concepts for Kentico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all sorts of videos on Kentico on the Kentico YouTube channel:

https://www.youtube.com/user/KenticoCMS/playlists

Specifically, the technical webinars may be of value to you:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9RdJplq_ukamszWm4UMmHmtfsebzjXKB

IN addition, the Kentico documentation has many pages / sections on the topics:

For Permissions:

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+permissions
http://blogs.jeroenfurst.nl/blog/september-2015/working-with-roles-and-permissions

For Worklfows:

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Using+workflows
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+workflows
http://www.mcbeev.com/Blog/September-2013/Anonymous-Blog-Post-Notifications-using-Advanced-Workflow-in-Kentico-CMS

Lastly, you can always find lots of great Q&As on DevNet:
http://devnet.kentico.com/questions-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can find videos on the Official Kentico YouTube channel
https://www.youtube.com/user/KenticoCMS/videos
or
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kentico+workflow

But video's are obsolete, you should use documentation
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+workflows